# Затираются изменения в файлах из git-репозитория

Tags: git

Не так давно столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Начинаю редактировать файл из репозитория git. Редактирую его некоторое время, пытаюсь сохранить, а редактор выдает сообщение о том, что сохранение невозможно, ибо файл был изменен внешней программой. При сравнении изменений видно, что каким-то образом файл был перезаписан на ту версию, которая была до начала редактирования. Сначала я грешил на SmartGit, но это продолжалось и тогда, когда он не был запущен. Потом начал грешить на редактор kate, однако, всё то же самое происходит и в VS Code. Может, кто сталкивался с таким? Я работаю под Linux Mint 19.

Comment: Вывод простой - не надо через git редактировать файлы.

Comment: То есть Вы предлагаете скопировать клон репозитория куда-то на диск, там всё редактировать, а оттуда периодически копировать в клон репозитория? Что-то я первый раз слышу про такое

Comment: а как именно Вы делаете это редактирование? обычно люди клонируют себе репозиторий локально. там его редактируют как хотят, потом коммит и пуш.

Comment: @HermannZheboldov а вы в курсе как гитом пользоваться? Опишите подробно, от А до Я, как это делаете

Comment: @KoVadim именно так и делаю, разумеется. До недавнего времени такой проблемы никогда не было

Comment: я видел такое с одной из gui поделок для работы с git. Эта приблуда делала pull по таймеру. И если два пользователя одновременно пытаются один документ потрогать, то у них были проблемы.

Comment: @InDevX клонирую репозиторий из ГитЛаба на локальную машину, правлю то, что мне нужно, коммичу изменения в локальный репозиторий, периодически пушу изменения в ГитЛаб

Comment: @KoVadim нет, это не то. Я для коммита-пуша юзаю SmartGit, но затирание случается и тогда, когда он выключен. Кстати, затирание не замечено, например, при использовании NetBeans или IntelliJ

Comment: зачем же использовать дополнительный софт, когда intellij и так отлично справляется с гитом?

Comment: @Эникейщик потому, что башевские скрипты мне гораздо удобнее редактировать в kate или в VS Code

Comment: попробуйте удалить полностью Smartgit и поработать консолью или другим тулом. Если проблема уйдет - причину я описал выше

Comment: @KoVadim, попробую. Хотя, я к нему сильно привык за последние лет шесть

Comment: он время от времени выдает такое, что ух. Один раз видел, как он показывал неверный граф веток. потом оказалось, что это была бага, но тимлиду, который готовил релиз это стоило много литров валерьянки.

Comment: В vscode есть расширения для работы с git, кстати.